# How do I display code overflowing the right screen border in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, word-wrap

When I add the preview, my code becomes hidden like the picture.

[image: Example of hidden lines of code]

I know that there is a shortcut to solve this but I do not remember which one. (I am on Mac).

I expect to have the shortcut in order to wrap the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to turn soft wrap on, which you can do with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, or by using the `View: Toggle Word Wrap` command.